# WSO2 Enterprise Integrator : Enable security on Data Services : The security token could not be authenticated or authorized

Tags: soap, wso2, ws-security, wso2-data-services-server, wso2-enterprise-integrator

My case is the following : I have WSO2 data services Unsecured, and I would like to enable WSS basic authentication (Username + password) (running on WSO EI 6.4.0)

In order to do it, I simply added the following in my data_service, and it is now correctly displayed as Secured.

```
<policy key="conf:repository/components/org.wso2.carbon.security.mgt/policy/scenario1"/>
   <enableSec/>
```

But my issue is the following : I can't make the call to this service work. No matter what I do, I always have the same response from the web service :

```
  <soapenv:Fault xmlns:axis2ns68="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <faultcode>axis2ns68:FailedAuthentication</faultcode>
     <faultstring>The security token could not be authenticated or authorized</faultstring>
     <detail/>
  </soapenv:Fault>
```

I am trying from SOAP UI, and I tried the following :

- No authentication set at all : no response from the service, just
  HTTP 401 Unauthorized
- Any authentication (WSS / BasicAuto,
  pre-emptively auth, ...) nothing is working, always the same error.

I also tried with the "try it" included in WSO2 : exact same issue.

I've read all the WSO2 logs (wso2carbon, wso2error, ...), and there is the same information as in the SOAP Fault, with a few additional lines from the Java stack, but completely useless

PS : I already did the same with an older version (WSO Data Service Server) and I had no issues at all, I followed all the new documentation, but I also found many Jira ticket open in the WSO2 EI open source project raising issues about this error returned "no matter what is the root cause"

Comment: can you attach the security policy to this

Comment: The policy scenario1 is one of the default policy, I didn't change anything in it.

Comment: I did a new from scratch default installation, enables the scenario1 policy and I have the exact same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found the solution. The default policies provided by WSO2EI cannot work as is (it worked as is in WSO2 DSS) :

The following section about the user / group authorization need to be added to the security policy :

```
<sec:CarbonSecConfig xmlns:sec="http://www.wso2.org/products/carbon/security">
    <sec:Authorization>
        <sec:property name="org.wso2.carbon.security.allowedroles">Internal/everyone,test</sec:property>
    </sec:Authorization>
</sec:CarbonSecConfig>
```